# Twitter integration in iphone

Tags: iphone

Ha ii ,i know how to integrate a Twitter in ios sdk,i alredy done with the help of MGTwitter Engine.But my problem is it shows a login page as a webview,i want to be login screen as popup just like the facebook login popup,so i got a [link](http://github.com/digdog/DDSocialDialog),that contains costomized popup for twitter,but how can i authenticate our twitter username and password in this costomized from.is there any other way to costomize our twitter logijn form?.please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Just if anyone is still stumbled to integrate twitter with native like effects.*

DETweetComposeViewController is really cool if you want to support devices lower than ios 5.
Its just a replica of Apple's TWTweetComposeView and very simple to use.

You need to follow steps at https://github.com/doubleencore/DETweetComposeViewController

Answer (score 1):

With iOS 5, the built-in twitter code checks up against the twitter account, that resides under the phone 'Settings'. So there should be no need to display the Twitter login in a popup. Or do I misunderstand your question ?

Comment: haiii,but i am not using the ios5.am using 4.3

Comment: Oh, okay. Then you can disregard my answer. With that said, you should consider upgrading. ;-)

Comment: is that possible to upgrade my current project to ios5?\

Comment: There should be no problem in upgrading. You might face some compilation errors, but they should be solvable. With iOS5 you can also benefit from ARC for your memory-handling.